# Azure DevOps Project Tags Through .NET Client?

Tags: .net, azure, api, azure-devops, devops

I'm trying to get access to the tags applied to an overall project from Azure DevOps so I can sync this info with other information on internal systems. The following using the .NET client can get all the tags from inside the project but not at project level. Is there anyway to do this? I've also tried getting the ID of the project collection to no avail.

```
        TeamProject proj = projectClient.GetProject("Project").Result;

        TaggingHttpClient taggingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<TaggingHttpClient>();
        WebApiTagDefinitionList tagList = taggingHttpClient.GetTagsAsync(proj.Id).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I think I found it.  I have no idea what the taggingHttpClient is supposed to do.  I can add tags with it.  I can then retrieve those tags with the API, but they don't show up as project tags!
I added a project tag through the DevOps web site, then tried API calls to retrieve it.  It does show up when you do a **GetProjectPropertiesAsync** call. So basically reversing that information, I did this, and it succesfully added a tag to my project.  Hope that helps.

`JsonPatchDocument eDoc = new JsonPatchDocument();
eDoc.Add(new JsonPatchOperation() { 
       Operation = Operation.Add, 
       Path = "/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Project.Tag.MyTagNameHere", 
       Value = "true" });
connection.ProjectClient.SetProjectPropertiesAsync(
         guidProject, 
         eDoc).SyncResult();`